# What is the status on Multiple Materials?

Tags: three.js

I cannot find any documentation on multiple materials - i know MultiMaterial has been deprecated but how does it work now?

Does three.js support this and if so how does faceVertexUvs map to multiple material (i mean a practicle example please)

Answer (score 1):

To apply multiple materials to an object, you are now able to assign them just as an array to the material property.

```
mesh.material = [material1, material2, material3];
```

See [Migration Guide (r84 → r85)](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#r84--r85):

> `MultiMaterial` has been removed. Use an Array instead.

The `faceVertexUvs` is a multidimensional array, where the first index represents the material index.

```
geometry.faceVertexUvs[ materialIndex ][ faceIndex ][ vertexIndex ]
```

(Reference: [three.js - geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][0][index] is not the same as geometry.vertices[index]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293290/three-js-geometry-facevertexuvs00index-is-not-the-same-as-geometry-verti))

The Three.js Docs could be indeed a bit better in both cases.